# Can't find any option to Create Collections in Cosmos db local storage/ Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm working with Azure Function and need to add "Collection Name" inside the cosmosdbtrigger attribute but there isn't any option there to create any collection, I am only able to create containers and hence while running the code on local storage it's causing the error :

> The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start.
>   [15-04-2020 22:39:01] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Either the source collection 'driverLocation' (in database 'pizza')  or the lease collection 'leases' (in database 'pizza') does not exist. Both collections must exist before the listener starts. To automatically create the lease collection, set 'CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists' to 'true'. Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: Message: {"Errors":["Resource Not Found"]}

Below is the boilerplate code that I am using, I have created the database and the collection in the cosmos db emulator

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
        databaseName: "pizza",
        collectionName: "driverLocation",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "pizzaConnection")] IReadOnlyList<Document> input,
            ILogger log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
                log.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].Id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is my local.settings.json file

```
    {
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "pizzaConnection": "AccountEndpoint=https://localhost:8081/;AccountKey=C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
    },
    "Host": {
        "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
        "CORS": "http://localhost:3872",
        "CORSCredentials": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but... the term *collection* is synonymous with *container.* Have you created a container in your Cosmos DB account? Also: please edit your question and post actual formatted text of any code and errors, not images of code & errors. Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) that explains the various reasons why.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a lease collection (also known as a container in CosmosDB and to specify a name for your lease collection in your Cosmos DB trigger like so:

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
    databaseName: "pizza",
    collectionName: "driverLocation",
    LeaseCollectionName = "leases"
    CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists: true,
    ConnectionStringSetting = "pizzaConnection")] IReadOnlyList<Document> input,
        ILogger log)
    {
        if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
            log.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].Id);
        }
    }
}
```

This should create a lease container for you if it doesn't exist. To create your collection using the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, you should see the following screen where you can create your container:

[image]

Essentially, just start the emulator, open it and then click "New Collection". Fill out the form to create your collection and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps, if you need any more information or have further questions let me know :)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I can't see "New collection" in the emulator so I'm assuming that it has been changed to "New Container"